# Send message to UITableViewCell from UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have designed a table view in my storyboard that uses many interface elements. For example, I have a cell with a `UIStepper` in it, and a cell that segues to another modal view. It contains static cells, as it is a simple data entry form and creating new `UITableViewCell` objects for each field would be a waste of time. However, I am using one custom cell from another point in the program. I have assigned the cell to be an instance of my custom `UITableViewCell` class, and have set the label and image view from the code (the custom cell is basic; two `UILabels` and a `UIImageView`). I set a placeholder image in the `viewWillAppear` method. The cell displays fine at first, however, when I change the label's text or the image in the code, the cell does not refresh until I tap it. I read that using custom table view cells was the solution to this problem when it occurred with basic `UITableViewCells`, however, this does not seem to solve my problem. Is there a method I can declare in custom cell that reloads the cell when the data is changed? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: code and screenshot is always helpful

Answer (score 0):

Once you have updated the information in the data source behind the cell (i.e. the image or text) you should call [`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW40) on the `UITableView`.